Zip File Structure Parsing Inconsistency, Deflating Zip File Via Binary File Manipulation
I am trying to parse a zip file using python, after locating the End Of Central Directory signature b'\x50\x4b\x05\x06' These are the extraction instructions I implemented using the zip file. It seems like ZIP (file format) - Wikipedia.
After copying the binary content of size compressed_size from file_header_offset I sometimes get an extra 4 bytes at the beginning of the output file.
Parsing Logic:
    # End Of Central Directory
    file.seek(centralDirOffset)
    res['disc_number'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(2), 'little')
    res['cd_start_disc'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(2), 'little')
    res['n_cd_on_disc'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(2), 'little')
    res['n_c_total'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(2), 'little')
    res['cd_size'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(4), 'little')
    res['cd_offset'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(4), 'little')
    res['comment_len'] = int.from_bytes(file.read(2), 'little')

    # Files Specific
    file.seek(res['cd_offset'])
    res['signature'] = binascii.hexlify(file.read(4)).decode("utf-8")
    res['version'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['min_ver'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['bit_flag'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['compression_method'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['f_last_modif_time'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['f_last_modif_date'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['crc_32'] = struct.unpack('<I', file.read(4))[0]
    res['compressed_size'] = struct.unpack('<I', file.read(4))[0]
    res['uncompressed_size'] = struct.unpack('<I', file.read(4))[0]
    res['f_name_length'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['extra_field_length'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['file_comment_length'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['disc_n_file_start'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['intern_file_attr'] = struct.unpack('<H', file.read(2))[0]
    res['extern_file_attr'] = struct.unpack('<I', file.read(4))[0]
    res['file_header_offset'] = struct.unpack('<I', file.read(4))[0]

    res['file_name'] = struct.unpack(f'{res["f_name_length"]}s', file.read(res['f_name_length']))[0].decode()
    res['extra_field'] = struct.unpack(f'{res["extra_field_length"]}s', file.read(res['extra_field_length']))[0]
    res['file_comment'] = struct.unpack(f'{res["file_comment_length"]}s', file.read(res["file_comment_length"]))[0].decode()

    # Skipping to file header
    res['file_offset'] = res['file_header_offset'] + 30 + res['f_name_length'] +           res['extra_field_length']
    res['file_size'] = res['compressed_size']

How to reproduce
Use the following function to get Central Directory offset of any zip file with Deflate compression method (id 8) with one file zip.
def findCentralDirectory(file):
    eocd_signature = b'\x50\x4b\x05\x06'
    file.seek(-22, 2)
    while True:
        h = file.read(4)
        if not h:
            logging.error("[!] Error -02: EOCD signature cannot be found. Make sure file is not corrupt.")
            sys.exit(-2)
        if h == eocd_signature:
            return file.tell()

What I am expecting
I am expecting the script to calculate the correct offsets to be able to decompress the result chunk via zlib.decompress.

You need to get the file name length and extra field length from the local header, and not use those values from the central header. The extra field lengths can be different in the central and local headers for the same entry. While the file name lengths should be the same, it is not forbidden by the format for them to be different, so you need get that length from the local header as well.
Your parsing of the zip format will only work for zip files that do not use the Zip64 extensions. Those are needed for large (> 4GB-1) zip files, zip files with large uncompressed entries (> 4GB-1), or with a large number of entries (>65535). You should read the PKWare APPNOTE.TXT for the full specification, as opposed to Wikipedia.
